# How to display variables values in a row with comma separator in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have four variables and I want to display their values in a row with comma separator. I have something like this:

```
{{first}}<span ng-show="first != '' && (second != '' || third != '' || forth != '')">, </span>
{{second}}<span ng-show="second != '' && (third != '' || forth != '')">, </span>
{{third}}<span ng-show="third!= '' && forth != ''">, </span>
{{forth}}
```

It works (see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6wtgy6po/)) but looks awful. Do you have any idea how to achieve this (without adding next variable) in more smart, elegance or useful way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at the array.join function. You can add a function to your scope to do the join, and filter out empty values. For instance:

```
$scope.joined = function() {
  return [$scope.first, $scope.second, $scope.third, $scope.forth]
    .filter(function(i) { return i; })
    .join(', ');
};
```

Then in your markup:

```
{{joined()}}
```

See this [fork](http://jsfiddle.net/vjowbqx4/) of your fiddle.

See the MDN docs for [Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) and [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: delete the first input and there's a floating coma at the begining

Comment: @gyc - Yes, I realized this right after I posted it. I've updated the code, and the link to a new fiddle.